# How to get value of transactions in blockchain from transaction hash?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

I have create a file with hash address. There any methods found this amount via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using web3.js you can pass transaction hash to a function like `web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash [, callback])` to get information about the transaction. It will also include a **value** field which you have passed to the transaction

Read more about transaction receipts and logs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransaction)

Answer (score 0):

in the bitcoin network to get transaction details from transaction hash then you can use get transaction RPC API call

https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettransaction.html

I have created videos for how to set up BTC node and work with RPC API call
https://youtu.be/_c4TJrP7osc

please watch it that might help you for how to setup